# How to show an exponential function is symmetric w.r.t. the y-axis.?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

The function $\dfrac{1}{2}x + \dfrac{x}{e^x -1}$ is symmetric w.r.t. the y-axis, and I want to demonstrate this. So I basically have to show that $$\dfrac{1}{2}x + \dfrac{x}{e^x -1} = - \dfrac{1}{2}x - \dfrac{x}{e^{-x} -1}$$

But I can't do this algebraically. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I ploted it and I didn't see any symmetric wrt to $y$ axes!!.

Comment: Add the fractions together before trying to prove it is symmetric.

Comment: @B.S. [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7Dx+%2B+%5Cdfrac%7Bx%7D%7Be%5Ex+-1%7D) certainly looks symmetric about the $y$-axis.

Comment: @JohnHabert: Oh yes. I made a mistake. Yes I see. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}x + \dfrac{x}{e^x -1}$$
$$=\frac{x(e^x+1)}{2(e^x-1)}$$ now what do you get for $f(-x)$. its the same $f(x)$.

Answer (score 5):

$$f(x) =\dfrac{1}{2}x + \dfrac{x}{e^x -1} = \dfrac {x(e^x - 1) + 2x}{2(e^x - 1)} = \dfrac{xe^x - x + 2x}{2(e^x - 1)} = \dfrac{xe^x + x}{2(e^x - 1)} = \dfrac{x(e^x + 1)}{2(e^x - 1)}$$

At this point, you should be able to convince yourself that $f(x) = f(-x)$.

Answer (score 1):

This means you have to show the function is even. Write $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}+ \frac{x}{e^x-1}$, which can be rewritten as $\frac12 \frac{x(e^x-1)+2x}{e^x-1}=\frac12 \frac{xe^x+x}{e^x-1}$. Then $f(-x)=\frac12 \frac{-xe^{-x}-x}{e^{-x}-1}\cdot \frac{-e^x}{-e^x}=\frac12 \frac{x +xe^x}{-1+e^x}=f(x)$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to algebraically get the answer from where you left off.

$$ - \frac{1}{2}x \ - \ \frac{x}{e^{-x} \ - \ 1} \ = \ - \frac{1}{2}x \ - \ \frac{xe^x}{1 \ - \ e^x } \ = \ - \frac{1}{2}x \ + \ \frac{xe^x}{e^x \ - \ 1} $$

Now , long division will give ,

$$ \frac{xe^x}{e^x \ - \ 1} \ = \ x \ + \ \frac{x}{e^x \ - \ 1} $$

And substituting gives ,

$$ - \frac{1}{2}x \ + \ x \ + \ \frac{x}{e^x \ - \ 1} \ = \ \frac{1}{2}x \ + \ \frac{x}{e^x \ - \ 1} $$